Vercel deployment dynamic route with error Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
On Vercel's deploy the routes are not working. In dev and build mode with localhost it's working perfectly.
Trying to do a GET request with dynamic route /products/[category] in /api/get-products gives the SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON in Vercel's project log.. I'm using pages router.
I already added CORS to next.config.mjs and process.env.VERCEL_URL to try avoid this error.
export default function Frame(props: { title: string, imageSrc: StaticImageData, styleName: string }) {
  return (
    <Link href={`http://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/products/${props.title}`} className={`${styles.container} ${styles[props.styleName]}`}>
      <div>
        <div className={styles.imageWrap}>
          <Image src={props.imageSrc} alt={props.title} fill/>
        </div>
        <Button text={props.title} styleNames={["catalog", props.styleName]}/>
      </div>
    </Link>   
  )

/products/[category]
export const getStaticPaths = (async () => {
  return {
    paths: [],
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}) satisfies GetStaticPaths

export const getStaticProps = (async (context) => {
  const category = context.params?.category as string

  const props: ProductsPageProps = {
    category: category,
  }
  
  const response = await fetch(`http://${process.env.VERCEL_URL}/api/products/get-products?` + new URLSearchParams({
    category: category
  }))
  
  if(response.status === 200) {
    props.products = await response.json()
  } else {
    props.error = await response.json()
  }

  return { props }
}) satisfies GetStaticProps<ProductsPageProps>

export default function Products({category, products, error}: InferGetStaticPropsType<typeof getStaticProps>) {
*\ Some code \* 
}


/api/get-products
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { PrismaClient, product } from '@prisma/client'
import ErrorResponse from "@/interfaces/ErrorResponse.interface";

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
}

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<product[] | ErrorResponse>) {
  try {
    const products: product[] =  await prisma.product.findMany({
      where: {
        category: req.query.category as string
      }
    })
    res.status(200).json(products)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({response: "Error querying the database"})
  }
}


